# PHP search many inputs

Tags: php, database, search

I have search field in which user can specify a lot of values to search like price, surface, year, garden, balcony etc.

In my search there is not even one field required every one is optional so user can provide 0 inputs filled or all.

Basically all this info's are saved in my database but I don't really know how to structure my code.

At the moment I have PHP file which I call from front and in this file I'm checking which field was filled and I'm executing method from class which do select to db and return data. This is working fine for every input separately but when I combain for example 2 different fields like price and surface then none of methods will be executed.

Im basically asking about an idea for architecture of search where user can fullfill many different fields. Im not using any PHP framework.

---

I could do something like:

`if(a & b & c & d & e & f) then execute method a`
`if(a & b & c & d & e) then execute method b`
`if(a & b & c & d) then execute method c`

and so on.. where this letters(a, b, c etc...) are `$_POST['something']` but I would have a lots of `if`'s to check which POST (which inputs) user fullfill and sent. Later on I would need to create a lot of methods in class with different SELECTs to db basing on which POST we have... I don't think that's best solution because I would basically repeat my code.

Comment: Are they `OR` or `AND`

Comment: I'd suggest having a snippet of SQL (i.e. part of a WHERE clause) for each possible search field, each held in a separate string. If the user wrote something in that field, concatenate that clause into your overall query (and add the appropriate parameter to your parameter list). I'm pretty sure I've written something of a similar nature before and that was how I did it. You still end up with an `if` for each field, but not for every possible combination of all the fields.

Comment: Thanks that's good idea I'll just combain string and do SELECT after all POSTs are checked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this

```
 $sql = 'SELECT * FROM sometable';
 $where = [];
 $params = [];

 if($a){
    $where[] = 'a = :a';
    $params[':a'] = $a;
 }

 if($b){
    $where[] = 'b = :b';
    $params[':b'] = $b;
 }


 if(!empty($where)){
    $sql .= ' WHERE '.implode(' AND ', $where);
 }

$stmt = $PDO->prepare($sql);
$res = $stmt->execute($params);
```

And so On.

It almost always preferable to use and array and implode for things like this instead of concatenation.  Often concatenation will leave you with a hanging "separator" in this case " AND ".  For example if we tried this with concatenation:

```
//if we put WHERE here and then nothing passes our conditions we wind up with:
//"SELECT * FROM sometable WHERE" which wont work
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM sometable ';

//we still need something like an array if we want to prepare our query.
//which is something we should always do
$params = []; 

 if($a){
    //if we put WHERE here, then what if this condition doesn't pass
    //do we put it in the next condition? How do we tell.     .
    $sql .= 'WHERE a = :a AND ';
    $params[':a'] = $a;
 }

 if($b){
     //again if the first condition didn't pass how do we know to put "WHERE" here.
    //"SELECT * FROM sometable b = :b AND" which wont work
    $sql .= 'b = :b AND ';
    $params[':b'] = $b;
 }

 if($c){
    //lets say the first 2 conditions passes but this last one failed
    //"SELECT * FROM sometable WHERE a = :a AND b = :b AND" which wont work
    $sql .= 'c = :c';
    $params[':c'] = $c;
 }

 //we would need to do something like this to trim the last "AND" off
 $sql = preg_replace('/\sAND\s$/', '', $sql);

 //--------------------
 //now if we were prepending "AND" instead of appending it, we're no better off.
 //--------------------
  //we can fix the where issue by using a string variable (and testing it latter)
  $where = '';

  if($a){
    $where .= 'a = :a';
    $params[':a'] = $a;
  }

  if($b){
    //However lets say the first condition failed, we get this:
    //"SELECT * FROM sometable WHERE AND b = :b" which wont work
    $where .= ' AND b = :b';
    $params[':b'] = $b;
    //--------------------------
    //so in every condition following we would have to test $where
    //and if its not empty then we can prepend "AND"
    if(!empty($where)) $where .= ' AND ';
    $where .= 'b = :b';
    $params[':b'] = $b;
 }

 if($c){
    if(!empty($where)) $where .= ' AND ';
    $where .= 'c = :c';
    $params[':c'] = $c;
  }


 //finally to fix the "WHERE" issue we need to do something like this:  
  if(empty($where)) $sql .= ' WHERE '.$where;

 //we could also try something like this in every condition:
  if($d){
    if(empty($where)) $where .= ' WHERE ';
    //However, this breaks our fix for prepending "AND", because 
    //$where will never be empty when we test it.
    //if(!empty($where)) $where .= ' AND ';
    $where .= 'd = :d';
    $params[':d'] = $d;
  }
```

Hopefully that all makes sense. It's just so much easier to use an array and `implode` it later.

I just wanted to show that to help visualize the issues with concatenation.  We wind writing more code, using the same number of variables and double the conditional logic.  Or we can get into complicated things like Regex to trim the hanging AND off etc.

Hope that helps!

**BECAUSE** I mentioned it in the comments.

If you are using "OR" you can of course do the same thing with that, but typically "OR" will cause a full scan of the DB.  It's just the way OR works. When we use "AND" the DB (basically) takes the return set and applies the next condition to that, because both have to pass.  However, with "OR" rows that failed the first condition could still pass if the second condition passes. So the DB must scan the full record set for each or, as well as keep track of all the rows that passed in the previous conditions.  It's just the way the logic works for "OR".

Now for improved "OR" performance we can use a sub-query that is a union. Like this:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM sometable AS t';
$union = [];
$params = [];


if($a){
   $union[] = 'SELECT id FROM sometable WHERE a = a:';
   $params[':a'] = $a;
}

if($b){
  $union[] = 'SELECT id FROM sometable WHERE b = b:';
  $params[':b'] = $b;
}

if(!empty($union)){
   $sql .= '
   JOIN( '.
        implode(' UNION ', $union).
   ' ) AS u ON t.id = u.id
}
```

What we wind up with is something like this query:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
   sometable AS t
JOIN (
     SELECT id FROM sometable WHERE a = a:
  UNION
     SELECT id FROM sometable WHERE b = b:
) AS u ON t.id = u.id
```

When we use "OR" as our dataset grows the DB must store these results in temp table as well as search the entire dataset.  Because we are pulling all the columns in the table, this dataset will quickly grow. Once it hits a certian size it will get swapped to Disc and our performance will take a big hit for that.

With the Union query, we also create a temp table. But because we are only concerned with pulling out the `ids` this temp table will be very small.  Union unlike Union ALL will also automatically remove duplicate records further reducing our dataset.  So we want to use Union and not Union ALL.

Then we join this back on the table in the outer query and use that to pull the all the columns from just the rows that we need.

Basically we are accepting the fact that we need a temp table and minimizing the impact of that.

This might not seem like it would be much faster, and in some cases it might not be (when no swapping happens).  But for me, using a query like you describe where users can search on multiple fields, I was able to reduce the time it took from about 15 seconds to under 1 second.  My query had several joins in it such as if a user put in a state, I had to join on `participant` then `participants_addresses` (junction table) and then `addresses` and then finally on `states`.  But if they put in a phone I had to join `participant > participants_phones > phone` etc.

I can't guarantee this will work in every case and you should use Explain and SQL_NO_CACHE when benchmarking your queries.  For example `EXPLAIN SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE * FROM ...`.  Explain will tell you how the indexes are working and No Cache prevents the DB from caching the query if you run it multiple times.  Caching will make it look like it is fast when it's really not.

You can do something similar when sorting, which also kills performance.

```
 SELECT
    *
 FROM
    sometable AS t
 JOIN (
        SELECT id FROM sometable WHERE a = a: ORDER BY date DESC
 ) AS u ON t.id = u.id
```

This has a similar effect of only sorting the id's in the temp table (instead of the whole dataset), and then when we join it, it actually keeps the order the ids are in.  I forget if the order of the subquery vs the outer query matter.

For fun you can even combine the two with 2 nested sub-queries, with the Union as the deepest query  (it's something like this).

```
 SELECT
    *
 FROM
    sometable AS t
 JOIN (
        SELECT id FROM sometable AS t0 JOIN (
             SELECT id FROM sometable WHERE a = a:
           UNION
             SELECT id FROM sometable WHERE b = b:
        ) AS u ON t0.id = u.id
        ORDER BY t0.date DESC
 ) AS t1 ON t.id = t1.id
```

It can get pretty complicated though ... lol.

Anyway, I was bored and maybe, just maybe, it will work for someone like it did for me.  (this is what happens when I don't get sleep) :)

**UPDATE**

IF you have problems with the parameters you can output the SQL with the values filled in by doing this:

```
   echo str_replace(array_keys($params), $params, $sql)."\n";
```

But use this only for Debugging, not for putting the data into the query because that would defeat the purpose of using prepared statements and open you up to SQLInjection attacks.  That said, it can make it easier to see if you are missing anything or have any spelling errors.  I also use this when I just want to test the query in PHPMyAdmin, but am to lazy to cut an paste the data into it.  Then I just copy the output put it in PHPMyAdmin and then I can rule out any issues with PHP or tweak the query if need be.

You can also have issues if you have to many elements in the array, AKA extra placeholders that are not in the query.

For that you can do

```
  //count the number of : in the query
  $num_placeholders = substr_count(':', $sql);
  //count the elements in the array
  $num_params = count($params);

  if($num_placeholders > $num_params ) echo "to many placeholders\n";

  else if($num_placeholders < $num_params ) echo "to many params\n";
```

One last thing to be mindful of when mixing "AND" and "OR" is stuff like this

```
 SELECT * FROM foo WHERE arg1 = :arg1 OR arg2 = :arg2  AND arg3 = :arg3
```

The way it executes this is like this

```
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE arg1 = :arg1 OR (arg2 = :arg2  AND arg3 = :arg3)
```

This will return all rows that match `arg1` regardless of the rest of the query.
Most of the time this would not be what you want. You would actually want it to do it this way:

```
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE (arg1 = :arg1 OR arg2 = :arg2)  AND arg3 = :arg3
```

Which is called an "Exclusive OR". This will return all rows that match `arg1` OR `arg2` AND `arg3`

Hope that helps.

Comment: I was about to answer something similar lol.

Comment: If they are `OR` however I would do Union sub-queries, it's much faster then OR,  For example make the outer query join the table on the sub-unions, then each union only selects the record id.  This way it minimizes the Temp table you need.  Or generally doesn't use indexes as well as AND does, so each Subquery can pull just it's ID using the index, then you join it to get the rest of the records data.

Comment: That's exacly what I was looking for, ty

Comment: Where should I bind this? Because I got error `Invalid parameter number: no parameters were bound `

Comment: It depends on what DB driver you are using, In my example I used PDO, if you use MySQLi it will be a bit different.

Comment: I'm using PDO and I have above error. doSearch is file which I call from front and this script build my query which then I pass to method in class take a look:
https://gist.github.com/BorysTyminski/bbb4e086dac97ebd9db8d6badca509d8

Comment: I had to add where to starting query because I'm comaining OR and ANDs by this implode function

Comment: I actually tried to bind in method but it gives another warning: `Warning: PDOStatement::bindParam() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given `

Comment: You don't have to explicitly bind with PDO, you can use an array in `execute()` as long as the placeholder names match.  As in my example.  I don't know what this word is `comaining`

Comment: combining*
execute() line throw error above, see screenshot https://imgur.com/a/RVFfawZ

Comment: Depending on your setting for PDO, you may have to have the `:` in the array keys, if you have placeholder `:something` and array key `something` it may not work unless you setup PDO to accept them that way.  Screenshots are all good and fine, but they don't show me what you are doing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179183/discussion-between-bt101-and-artisticphoenix).

Comment: See example #2 http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php  again without seeing what you have now I can do much to help.   You can put **UPDATE** and add it to the question, but don't remove the original stuff as it can make it confusing to other users.

Comment: Ahh so I need to pass params array to execute function?

Comment: That's what I put in the first part of the answer `$res = $stmt->execute($params);` so yes.  You can bind them individually, but it's easier to do it as an array in most cases.

Comment: Now I have `var_dump($params); $return = $stmt->execute($params);` and when I execute it take a look: https://imgur.com/a/2IRvQAy

Comment: How the parameter is not defined I var dump it line above and it show correct array..

Comment: Oh nevermind I found issue it was typo in file in which i'm combining query

Comment: I was going to say see my last update ... :)

Comment: I also added a cautionary note about mixing "AND" and "OR" and what an "Exclusive OR" is.

Answer (score 0):

You could also create an wanted list of nesseccary items and Check If each Item is Set by the PHP function isset().